# Failed to restore NuGet package - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, signalr, nuget-package-restore, aspnetboilerplate

I'm getting an error message:

> Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR with version (>=
>   1.0.0-preview1-27891)
>     - Found 3 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 1.0.0-alpha2-final ]
>     - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    MaiPiuSprechi.Web.Core  C:\PROGETTI\MaiPiuSprechi\3.4.1\aspnet-core\src\MaiPiuSprechi.Web.Core\MaiPiuSprechi.Web.Core.csproj

Framework: ABP + .NET Core (version 3.4.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered in this issue: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2831

> Add this file to the same folder as your **.sln** file: [NuGet.Config](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/5e8d3336bb27d747036d8b66e6b82afe88037ad1/NuGet.Config)

**NuGet.Config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="aspnetcore-dev" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```